# How to get multiple scope_identity from table then insert to other table?

Tags: sql-server

brothers, can you help me?
Sample Query:

```
     DECLARE @id_scope TABLE (ID_TBA_PK int)
     Insert into TABLE_A
         Select ID_TBA_PK,ID_LET_FK,NAME, ADDRESS FROM TABLE_A WHERE 
         ID_LET_FK=@ID_LET_FK 
         set @id_scope  = scope_identity()  --but must get multiple identity 
         -- because above insert multiple,ID_TBA_PK is autoincement.
```

then insert to table others:

```
    insert into TABLE_B
              select ID_TBA_FK=@id_scope , NAME, ADDRESS FROM TABLE_B
              WHERE ID_TBA_FK=@ID_TBA_FK 

    --(MULTIPLE INSERT TO TABLE_B)
```

Comment: HIi It's Seem you try to Insert multiple Row in Detail Table for eg:-Table_B is your Detail.my question is #id_scope is same for all the row or it will change.Suppose 1st row #id_scope is 10 so for Next Row it will be 11 or 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `OUTPUT` clause to your `INSERT`.  Something like this:

`INSERT TABLE_A(NAME, ADDRESS, etc.)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID_TBA_PK into @id_scope
Select ID_TBA_PK,ID_LET_FK,NAME, ADDRESS FROM TABLE_A WHERE 
         ID_LET_FK=@ID_LET_FK`

This line I am assuming ID_TBA_PK is your new identity

`OUTPUT Inserted.ID_TBA_PK into @id_scope`

so the general case is

```
INSERT [table] (columns)

OUTPUT INSERTED.[column] into [@other table]

SELECT columns from .....
```

Comment: where i fill your query in my query bro?

Comment: how @id_scope  insert to table others?, look my ask question above.

Comment: You can select from TABLE_A joined to `@id_scope` into TABLE_B or you can extend `@id_scope` to have all the columns you need from TABLE_A and grab them in the OUTPUT clause in the initial query.